# Using CartoCSS to have polygon change shape or symbol upon different zoom levels?

Tags: carto, cartocss

I'm working with some small area parcel data.  When zoomed in it is important to see the actual polygon shape.  But when zoomed out, something like a simple point marker that scales would be better, otherwise the small polygon isn't really visible.

Is there a way to dictate this with CartoCSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the magic of PostGIS and the elegance of CartoCSS!

First, style your polygon layer to include a scale threshold - I'll choose scales greater than 12 for the polygons (ie. zoomed in beyond 12):

```
#census_neighborhood_demographics_2010
{

  [zoom > 12]{

  polygon-fill: #FF6600;
  polygon-opacity: 0.7;
  line-color: #FFF;
  line-width: 0.5;
  line-opacity: 1;

  }
}
```

Now click the + Icon in the CartoDB panel to add another layer

Choose the same polygon layer you styled above, but go into the SQL panel and use the ST_Centroid function to change the geometry of the polygons to points:

```
SELECT 
ST_Centroid(points.the_geom_webmercator) as the_geom_webmercator
 , cartodb_ID
FROM census_neighborhood_demographics_2010 as points
```

Note that I've only grabbed `the_geom_webmercator` from the attribute columns of the polygons, and the `cartodb_id` column as well.

Now the CartoCSS for the new 'point' layer should have a similar scale definition, but I'll choose scales LESS THAN OR EQUAL to 12 (ie. zoomed out to 12 and beyond):

```
#census_neighborhood_demographics_2010{
   [zoom <= 12]{

  marker-fill-opacity: 0.9;
  marker-line-color: #FFF;
  marker-line-width: 1;
  marker-line-opacity: 1;
  marker-placement: point;
  marker-type: ellipse;
  marker-width: 10;
  marker-fill: #FF6600;
  marker-allow-overlap: true;
  }
}
```

So now at zoom levels above 12, I see polygons:
[image]
And zoom levels less than or equal to 12, I see points!

[image]

One dataset - multiple visualizations and geometry representations!

Comment: Great!  I couldn't see past the single layer ... Now, does this mean that info windows would need to be styled the same way to get consistent interaction?

Comment: Most likely... but you can make some choices about what scales to show those infowindows and what the content needs to be... but you can always copy and paste the HTML from one layer to the other (as long as the point layer was selecting the same fields as the polygon layer, so that the HTML tags would have the columns available...) does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, once I actually, went through your workflow I saw that of course, one can now decide what info-window is most appropriate for the scale.  And yes, the HTML tags / CSS needs to be able to reference the appropriate columns ... so the SQL you provided can be amended to make available the desired columns.

Comment: @AdamC right on! Have fun!